# How do I pass username variable from markup to a php code?

Tags: php, ajax, web-services, authentication

I have a php webservice called proxyCreate.php that passes two values, username and password to an API that authenticates user credentials.

This works fine.

However, the API returns only returns only authenticated username, password and date of the authentication.

We would also like to grab the deptID of the user but unfortunately, the API does not the ability to do this and we have no control over what the API returns.

As a result, I am trying to query the database table to return the DeptID associated with an authenticated user.

So far, I am getting an error that says, "An invalid parameter was passed to SQL_Srv query"

Is there anyway around this?

Here is what I have so far.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

session_start();

// Connect to SQL Server database
include("../../connections/Connect.php");

$upass = $_GET['upass'];
// Construct query

$tsql =
"
SELECT
    ISNULL([ORGANIZATION],'')

FROM
 [EMPLOYEE]
WHERE Lower([LOGINNAME]) = lower('$upass')
";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
if( $stmt === false )
{
     echo "Error in executing query.</br>";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
$results = array();
// Retrieve and display the results of the query
//$lastFeatType = "";
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($results,$row);
}

 echo json_encode($results);

// Free statement and connection resources
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
sqlsrv_close( $conn);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>
    FTS Service Requests
</h1>
  <div class="action-container" style="display:none;"></div>


   <div id="tabs">
  <ul>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p style="font-size:14pt;">User Log In</p>
</div>
  </ul>
<p>
</p>
<br clear="all" />
<div>
     <br />   <br />
      <br />
       <?php
        //Start session
         session_start();
         header("Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
         header("Pragma: no-cache");
         header("Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT");
         if(!empty($_GET['status'])){
                echo '<div align=center><font color=firebrick>You have been logged out!</font><br><br>Log in again or close browser.</div>';
         }
       ?>
       <br />
        <br />
      <br />
      <form id="FormToValidate">
        <table>
         <tr>

           <td nowrap>
                   <div class="input text">
              <label><strong>UserName:</strong></label>
              <input  maxlength="40" class="required" name="user" id="user" size="20" placeholder="Enter username!" type="text" title="Please enter a username." tabindex="2" value="" style="width:400px;color:#000;font-size:10pt;height:20px;" />
            </div>
          </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td nowrap>
               <div class="input text">
                <label><strong>Password:</strong></label>
                <input  maxlength="40" class="required" name="pass" id="pass" size="20" placeholder="Enter password!" type="password" tabindex="3" title="Please enter a password." value="" style="width:400px;color:#000;font-size:10pt;height:20px;" />
               </div>
              </td>

         </tr>

         <tr>
            <td></td>
              <td>
              <div class="buttonSubmit">
              <input type="button" id="btnValidate" style="width:80px; margin-left:-152px;background-color:#fff;" value="Log In" />
             </div><br clear="all"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#btnValidate").click(function() {

// Creating variables to hold data from textboxes

var uname = $("#user").val();
var upass = $("#pass").val();

$.post("proxyCreate.php",
  { data: JSON.stringify({ LoginName: uname,Password: upass }) })
    .done(function(data) {
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
        switch(result.Status) {
            case 0:
                //login successful
                tokenVal = result.Value.Token;
                location.href = "http://Accounts/accounts.php?token="+tokenVal+ "&user=" + uname;
                break;

            case 2:
                //invalid login
                alert(result.Message);
                break;
        }
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert("The AJAX request failed!");
    });
  });
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wait... So passwords in this system are: 1) Stored in a field called `LOGINNAME`, 2) Stored in *plain text*, and 3) *Not* case-sensitive?  *And* the code is SQL-injectable.  I suspect getting the `DeptID` is the least of the concerns here...

Comment: @David, NO. As the name suggests, that's login name or username, not password. As stated, they are passed to an API and you can't see it. Everything goes through proxyCreate.php. I have no idea how you reached your conclusions.

Comment: The SQL query suggests otherwise... `WHERE Lower([LOGINNAME]) = lower('$upass')`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the form post isn't being handled correctly.  Note that it's a POST method...

```
$.post(...
```

However, in the code you're looking for a GET value:

```
$upass = $_GET['upass'];
```

This would result in no value in `$upass`.  You'd want to use the `$_POST` array:

```
$upass = $_POST['upass'];
```

Additionally, it looks like the page is checking for the value in one place:

```
if(!empty($_GET['status'])){
```

But isn't checking for the value before running the actual query.  That same `if` block should be used around that query to make sure that the value has been supplied before trying to find the `DeptID` from the database.

Finally, it looks like you're mixing up server-side and client-side order of operations.  Is this the page being posted to by the AJAX request?  The response isn't going to be what you expect.  You're echoing JSON data:

```
echo json_encode($results);
```

But the rest of the page still executes, so all of that HTML markup is going to be returned as well.  This may confuse the JSON parser client-side.  I would recommend separating the UI page from the JSON service into two separate files.

Answer (score -1):

```
$tsql =
"SELECT ISNULL([ORGANIZATION],'') FROM [EMPLOYEE]
WHERE Lower([LOGINNAME]) = lower('".$upass."')
";
```

Comment: and David, I see it now. My apologies. I meant to say $uname but still doesn't suggest it is plain text as they are passed to an API.

I think that the issue has to do with both the markup and php being on same page?

Any ideas from the experts would be greatly appreciated.